# Google Awareness API with Beacons MAC

Tags: android, beacon, google-awareness

I have some custom beacons for communicating via Bluetooth LE. Currently I am performing an LE-scan and check if the MAC-address of any found BLE-device is one of mine.

I would like to use Google Awareness Fence API to get triggered, if one of my beacons is in range instead of implementing the whole stuff by myself. But, if I want to create such a `AwarenessFence`, I only can define the attributes

- Namespace,
- Type

when using the TypeFilters:

```
final BeaconState.TypeFilter typeFilter = BeaconState.TypeFilter.with("abc", "def");
    final AwarenessFence beaconFence = BeaconFence.found(typeFilter);
    Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(
            client,
            new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
                    .addFence(BEACON_FENCE, beaconFence, pi)
                    .build())
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Fence was successfully registered.");
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Fence could not be registered: " + status);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Questions:

1. What does namespace and type mean? Are these attributes given to all BLE devices and can I read them somehow from my beacons? Or is this e.g. something Eddystone specific?
2. Can I use the Awareness API with MAC addresses of my beacons?

Answer (score 4):

1) Had the same problem and solved it.

From https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/attachments you get a attachment context with a field "namespaceType". All you have to to is splitt up the hole String from "namespace/type" to "namespace" and "type" for your FenceState.TypeFilter. The namespace should be your project-id form the GoogleDevConsole.

To setup your beacon get the "Beacon Tools"(Google Inc.) from GooglePlayStore and find your beacon, there you can add an attachment.

---

2) As far as I can see: When a fence is triggered, you only get the fence key. So the answere is NO. But you could make a getBeaconState()-request, to see which beacons are near to you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do I get it right: These attributes are only available for beacons that are configured with Google API's e.g. Proximity Beacons registered in Google's cloud. That's bad, would be cool, it would work without the cloud stuff. But nevertheless thanks!

Comment: ATM I found no other way to add there attributes successfully.